# Microsoft Teams, Incoming Webhook Connector, Configuration Save 403 Error

Tags: webhooks, microsoft-teams

When I type in a name for the Incoming Webhook connector in Microsoft Teams and save the configuration I end up getting a 403 error:

[image]

Is there a permission or configuration option that I need to use this connector?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there's just a delay after enabling the connector and being able to save configuration details for it. Working now and nothing was changed on our end.